# Android WebView overlaps with other views

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a simple web view in between image and button. For some reason, if I put a long text, the web view is overlapping with the logo and the button. It works for a short text. I used constraint layout. It seems that the web view is expanding beyond the parent view.

Please see the pictures.

Below is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_big_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/login_cashnetusa_color"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_splash_screen"
        style="@style/CardTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_cta"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_logo">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_header"
                style="@style/CardContent.CustomBlack.Bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_normal_margin"
                android:text="@string/dummy_full_name"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wv_update_text"
                style="@style/CardContent.White"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_normal_margin"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_header" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cta"
        style="@style/Button.OrangeGradient"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_normal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_normal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_item_normal_margin"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_skip"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/dummy_btn_ok" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_skip"
        style="@style/CardContent.White"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_normal_margin"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in here:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_splash_screen"
    style="@style/CardTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    <-- change layout:height from wrap_content to some specific height let it be 300-400dp -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_cta"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_logo">
```

or the second option is you can use minHeight and maxHeight in your cardview or it's child layout which is Constraint layout to prevent it from expanding on full screen 
and if you have long texts to read use ScrollView inside cardview.

Answer (score 0):

As you have set the height of your CardView to wrapContent it will expand to the content that is put in it, what you can do is set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` that will prevent it from expanding beyond its bounds.

Note that you do have to set up the view bound chaining properly for this to work, ie set `app:layout_constraintTop_toX` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toX` on all the views in the 'chain' from the top of the view through to the bottom.

so in your code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_splash_screen"
    style="@style/CardTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_normal_outer_margin"
    <!-- add this line --> app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_cta"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_logo">
```